# Why the os cannot detect any usb device between system update and reboot

Tags: usb, arch-linux, updates, reboot

I always wondered why after every system update I had to reboot the machine in order to mount an usb device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During upgrade of the `linux` package (just like any other package), all files belonging to the old version are removed. This includes all *kernel modules* found in the `/lib/modules/<version>` directory. So the system can no longer auto-load modules for that version.

For example:

1. You boot using kernel `4.12.99`, but later upgrade the package to `4.13.0`.
2. When you connect a new device type (for which modules haven't been loaded *yet*), the system still looks in the directory for the *current* version, that is `/lib/modules/4.12.99`.
3. But since the package was upgraded, the files aren't there anymore.

*(Note that this **only** affects upgrades which changed the current kernel package. If it happens every time, then perhaps you are not upgrading the system frequently enough...)*

You have a few possible workarounds:

- You can temporarily *downgrade* the kernel package to whatever version is currently running; reconnect the devices; and upgrade again. Once the needed modules get loaded, they'll just stay loaded.
- TYou can find out which modules are frequently used (e.g. what's needed for flash drives) and load them *on boot*. Again, once loaded, they'll stay loaded and won't be affected by upgrades anymore.

  1. On a freshly-rebooted system, run `lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | sort > before.txt` to produce a list of modules currently present.
  2. Connect your flash drives, adapters, mice, whatever else you use often. That'll result in all necessary modules being loaded.
  3. Run `lsmod | awk '{print $1}' | sort > after.txt` to create the updated list.
  4. Use `diff before.txt after.txt` to determine the new names.
  5. Finally, create a file `/etc/modules-load.d/something.conf` containing just the names you obtained in step #4, one per line.
- If this were Gentoo or a similar distribution, you could compile the same features into the kernel itself (i.e. not as modules) so they'd be permanently present.
- In some advanced cases (when you already know the module name but can't reboot nor obtain the correct version), if the upgrade was only between minor releases (e.g. 4.13.1 to 4.13.2), there is a chance that you can just `insmod` the *new* module file and it'll still work despite the version mismatch.